# How to set directory for exported headers when building a static library in XCode 5?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I configured my project to include a subproject with a static c++ library as target. In XCode 4 it was possible to set a destination path where the headers are copied to after building the library. See the image below:

[image: XCode 4: Build Phases / Copy Files Screenshot]

Where is the option in XCode 5?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode menu bar -> Editor -> Add Build Phase -> Add Copy Headers Build Phase
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/Setting%20the%20Role%20of%20a%20Header%20File.html